# dotnet core Storing objects in RedIs

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, redis, deserialization

Using .NET Core, I am trying to save and retrieve a JSON Array of the object from Redis using IDistributedCache.  Below is my code for storing and reading from Redis cache:

```
public void Save(string key, object content, int duration)
    {
        string s;
        if (content is string)
        {
            s = (string)content;
        }
        else
        {
            s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        }

        duration = duration <= 0 ? DefaultCacheDuration : duration;
        Cache.Set(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration)
        });
    }

public T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        var c = Cache.Get(key);
        if (c == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return str as T;
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
    }
```

the object that I want to store is

```
 public class RuleLoadCollection_Result
{
    [Key]
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
}
```

In my biz logic, am saving the object like this

```
 public IQueryable<RuleLoadCollection_Result> GetRuleLibrary()
    {
        var result = _dbClient.GetRuleLibrary();
        _cache.Save("TestKey", result);
        return result;
    }
```

the output here is an Array of Object.

```
[{"ruleId":1,"ruleName":"a1"}]
```

What code should I write to return the same array of objects from cache? I tried a few options, most of them gave compile or runtime errors.  After the bit of browsing, I tried below, it worked, but it is giving only the first element of the array.

```
public RuleLoadCollection_Result GetRuleLibraryFromCache()
    {
        return (_cache.Get<List<RuleLoadCollection_Result>>("TestKey").First());
    }
```

output for this is

```
{"ruleId":1,"ruleName":"a1"}
```

which I understand why, but what c# should I write to JSON array back which I saved?

below code gives the runtime error

```
public IQueryable<RuleLoadCollection_Result> GetRuleLibraryFromCache()
    {
        return (_cache.Get<IQueryable<RuleLoadCollection_Result>>("TestKey"));
    }
```

the runtime error is:

> Cannot create and populate list type System.Linq.IQueryable`1[RuleLoadCollection_Result]. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
public IQueryable<RuleLoadCollection_Result> GetRuleLibraryFromCache()
    {
        var result = _cache.Get<IEnumerable<RuleLoadCollection_Result>>("TestKey").AsQueryable();
        return result;
    }
```